# Find common elements in two string list java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, string-comparison

i have two  String list in java and i want to get common element of two list.
I use the retainAll method but it doesn't work

```
String csv = "Apple, Google, Samsung";
List<String> csvList = Arrays.asList(csv.split(","));
ArrayList<String> list0= new ArrayList<String>(csvList);
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("Apple");
list1.add("Asus");
list1.add("Lenovo"); 
list1.add("Google");
list1.retainAll(list0);
```

list1.retainAll(list0); return list1 empty . list1 must return ==>  "Apple, Google, Samsung"

how can i return a list of common element in two string list please help.

Comment: Both @maveriq and @Wahid have pointed out the issue. Best way to handle is to ensure the input is consistent either by changing the input string or by manually trimming the spaces. 

One quick and dirty 'hack' is to include the extra space after comma as your delimiter for split `List<String> csvList = Arrays.asList(csv.split(", "));` (note there is a space after the comma)

Comment: The best way to have diagnosed this would have been to step through the code with the debugger, carefully looking at the values in csvList.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in your input string:

```
String csv = "Apple, Google, Samsung";
```

When parsing, spaces are not automatically truncated, so later `retainAll` interprets them as different strings, like `Google` and  `Google`.

You can either remove your spaces from the input string or trim them manually.

Correct output for your inputs would be:

```
[Apple, Google]
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: `String csv = "Apple, Google, Samsung";`

After the split, the second and third elements will be  `Google` and  `Samsung`, which are different from `Google` and `Samsung`.